# How common is it for AC evaporation coils to develop leaks after three months?

Tags: hvac

Bought new Goodman HVAC unit in September 2022. Evaporator coil has a leak after three months and needs to be replaced. How common is it for that to happen?

Comment: It was either made defectively or installed wrong.  They should last years.

Comment: Just to be clear: are we talking a refrigerant leak or a water/condensate leak?

Answer (score 5):

That isn't common at all. Those coils should last for many years. Luckily, your unit should be under full warranty unless you installed it yourself and possibly voided the warranty. Get with the company who you purchased the unit from or the person who installed it. I would be wanting a new coil, not a repair job.

Answer (score 1):

Defective manufacturing.

Normally the HVAC last at least 5 or 10 years.

Hopefully you registered your HVAC with in 60 days from purchase date

Below is the link to register it

From Goodman website

> Though not required to get the protection of the standard warranty, registering your product within 60 days of installation entitles you to additional warranty coverage, except that failure by California and Quebec residents to complete this registration form does not diminish their warranty rights. To expedite the process, we ask that you have the following:
> The serial numbers of the equipment you purchased.
> The general information, including name, address and phone number.
> The name and phone number of the dealer who installed your equipment.

[registration](https://www.goodmanmfg.com/product-registration)